# Getting ModuleNotFoundError in Django

Tags: python, django

[image]

Project Structure

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('login_user', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
    path('logout_user', views.logout_user, name='logout_user'),
    path('register_user', views.register_view, name='register_user'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

**chat_app2/views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from chat_app2.account.forms import RegistrationForm

def register_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponse("You are already authenticated as " + str(user.email))

    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email').lower()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            destination = kwargs.get("next")
            if destination:
                return redirect(destination)
            return redirect('homepage')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'register_user.html', context)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'account',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

**Error**

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Manish Gusain\Documents\Python_Projects\chat_app2\chat_app2\urls.py", line 3, in <module>

    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\Manish Gusain\Documents\Python_Projects\chat_app2\chat_app2\views.py", line 4, in <module>

    from chat_app2.account.forms import RegistrationForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chat_app2.account'
```

I'm trying to add new user to the database using a user registration form but when I make migrations this is the error I'm getting. It can't find the module `chat_app2.account` . I have added the app in Installed_Apps even though django's unable to recognize it.

Comment: try this `from account.forms import RegistrationForm`

Comment: @AliAref Already tried this. It's not working.

Comment: can you share the error that you get after using account.forms

Comment: @Loukik If I do that it shows `Unresolved reference`  and new user is not added to database.

Comment: @ManishGusain Try this path : `from ..account import forms`..Attention: use **double dot** before the **account**...and put `form = forms.RegistrationForm(request.POST)`

Comment: @Pradip Now it's showing this error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`